# What is the purpose of the Configurations2 directory inside of an ODF-Document?

Tags: openoffice.org, specifications, text-processing, odf, odt

The directory is not mentioned in the OASIS-Specification of ODF. Does anyone know the purpose of this directory?

Its structure is as follows:

```
accelerator/current.xml
floater
images/Bitmaps
menubar
popupmenu
progressbar
statusbar
toolbar
toolpanel
```

There is no content in the directories or files inside this dubious folder.

Comment: It's mentioned in the book [*OASIS OpenDocument Essentials*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=-AasoVVqNU8C&pg=PA6&lpg=PA6&dq=application/vnd.sun.xml.ui.configuration&source=bl&ots=T-vIDATm8X&sig=ACfU3U09YR5hZzTh8ysXBlYks7okfL9tVw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjfgvDSopbgAhUr04MKHct_A-AQ6AEwBXoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=Configurations2&f=false) by J. David Eisenberg: `I'm not sure what this directory contains!` :/